# use large app icon from older version in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, version, app-store-connect

I have an app in AppStore.

When I want to release new version of my app, iTunes Connect requires to update large app icon:

> You must upload a large app icon.

Why iTunes Connect can't use large app icon from previous version of my app?

p.s. I could be wrong, but when I update my app before (some months ago), there was no need to update large app icon.

Answer (score 1):

Some months ago (many months, in reality), iTunes Connect required a "large" 512x512 app icon.

Now they require a 1024x1024 icon. My suggestion, in case you don't have access to the vectorial graphic or cannot generate again, is trying to up-sample the icon. I would try Photoshop or another image editor that has options to upscale with corrections.

Comment: thank you for the advice. indeed, i cannot generate icon again, but i have the same icon (by the way, it's 1024x1024) in previous version of the app. i found way to extract icon url from appstore (via html page source code). so problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I literally did it 2 mins ago.

The recipe:
Log into your iTunes Connect account, go to your app and to the `General App Information` section. Your should see your app's icon. right click and `inspect element`. Search for the image URL. The image URL should have a suffix like: `/150x150bb.jpg` just change it into: `1024x1024bb.jpg` and u should have the full sized image you once uploaded.

Comment: This will fetch image with a white background. We need an image with the Transparent background.

Comment: Use Sketch or PS to remove the white background, btw I don't think Apple will let you upload images with transparent background